# Play framework null checkbox list

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am new to play framework having some dificulties in accesing check box in controller. My view is:-

```
@(img:Form[Image])
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.abc) {
    <li><input name="item[0]" value="pt" type=checkBox></li>
            <li><input name="item[1]" value="sumit" type=checkBox></li>
    <p>
               <button type=submit id=imgButton>submit</button>
    </p>

    }
```

My conntroller is:-

```
def abc = Action{
    implicit request =>
      val values =ImageForm.bindFromRequest.get
      println("mapinggg"+values)
      Ok("hi")
  }
```

My case class to handle checkbox is:-

```
case class Image (desc:List[String])
```

and form is

```
val ImageForm =Form(
       mapping(
           "desc" -> list(text)
           )(Image.apply)(Image.unapply)
       )
```

But it returns nill when I click on submit by selecting checkbox?
It gives output as Image(List()) but I want list of selected checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of your inputs ("item" - without the indices) needs to match the key of your list mapping (here given as "desc") for the binding to succeed. It should work if you change the ImageForm mapping to:

```
val ImageForm =Form(
   mapping(
       "item" -> list(text)
   )(Image.apply)(Image.unapply)
)
```

Note that the actual *field name* in your case class - "desc" - should not matter here.

Comment: It works but it shows output as  Image(List(acepted, images/pics/6.jpg")) and I could not retrive individual ellements from List.How to iterate in this list.